# Block ui except the correct record on primefaces

Tags: user-interface, jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 5.0 with spring webflow. I have the page with datatable which lists out the records and there is one record access from another page. As user request if I choose view one record which will redirect to the another page of datatable, she want to block the UI of other records and place a button at the bottom of the data table for admin to unblock the records or auto unblock after 10 seconds.

I have no idea on how to block the ui or unblock. Do you have any ideas??

Thanks for your help,

Comment: What about `p:blockui`? Or a modal dialog